# How to highlight objects that repeat within 30 days?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Similar to my question, I want to highlight the objects that repeat within 30 days according to current date. for eg when I bought an object on 01-01-2022, if i buy that product again after 20 days then those objects must highlight(because the range is within 30 days). then after 15 days i buy the same product again then it must highlight like which i bought second and third time ( because first buy and third buy are more than 30 days and second buy and third buy are within 30 days).

Hope you got what i need. sorry for my bad english.. here a sheet shared below. there you can see an estimated output too.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bdWKHtW6SA6XI5pIZUrlLQJLi-Gywx2iYUqxFWY1e0I/edit#gid=567292972

Estimated output for today's date 20-Jul-2022 (highlighted cells are bold):

| DATE | PRODUCT |
| --- | --- |
| 01-Jul-2022 | PEN |
| 02-Jul-2022 | CHAIR |
| 07-Jul-2022 | **GLASS** |
| 20-Jul-2022 | KEY |
| 21-Jul-2022 | CHAIN |
| 22-Jul-2022 | **PEN** |
| 05-Aug-2022 | **GLASS** |
| 06-Aug-2022 | CHAIR |
| 07-Aug-2022 | **PEN** |

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 2):

#### Highlight product if purchased within thirty days of last purchase

```
function hili() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  const x = {};
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!x.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
      x[r[1]] = new Date(r[0])
    } else {
      if (DiffInDays(x[r[1]], new Date(r[0])) >= 30) {
        sh.getRange(i + 2, 2).setBackground("yellow");
        x[r[1]] = new Date(r[0]);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

[image]

#### DiffInDays:

```
function DiffInDays(Day1,Day2) {
  if(Day1 && Day2 && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day1) === '[object Date]') && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day2) === '[object Date]')) {
    var day=86400000;
    var t1=new Date(Day1).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(Day2).valueOf();
    var d=Math.abs(t2-t1);
    var days=Math.floor(d/day); 
    //Logger.log(days);
    return days;
  } else {
    throw 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Alas. The estimated output look like this: https://imgur.com/UBEC5wP.png but this code gets this: https://imgur.com/Wd43MnS.png

Answer (score 0):

Quite clumsy, but it works (I hope):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var colors = range.setBackground('').getBackgrounds();
  var data = range.getValues().reverse();
  var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)
  var thirty_days = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
  var index = 0;

  while (data.length) {
    let [date, product] = data.shift();
    let same_product_index = data.map(x => x[1]).indexOf(product);
    if (same_product_index) {
      let dates = data.map(x => x[0]);
      let product_date = new Date(date).getTime();
      let same_product_date = new Date(dates[same_product_index]).getTime();

      // conditions
      let cond1 = Math.abs(product_date - same_product_date) < thirty_days;
      let cond2 = Math.abs(same_product_date - today) < thirty_days
      let cond3 = Math.abs(product_date - today) < thirty_days
      let cond4 = colors[index][1] != 'yellow';

      if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4) {
        colors[index][1] = 'yellow';
        colors[index + same_product_index + 1][1] = 'yellow';
        }
    }
    index++;
  }

  range.setBackgrounds(colors.reverse())
}
```

Output:

[image]

Note: I changed date in the row 4 to '**07**-Jul-2022'. Since I don't understand why in your estimated output the row 4 (03-Jul-2022 GLASS) is highlighted. There are more than 30 days between '03-Jul-2022 GLASS' and '05-Aug-2022 GLASS'.